# Proof that $F(x)=0$ and $F(x)=1$ (cumulative distribution function of a real-valued)

Tags: probability

I want to prove that if all values of a real random variable $X$ are in the interval $[a, b]$ with $a <b$, then $F(x) = 0$ for all $x < a$ and $F (x) = 1$ for all $x \geq b$.

So note that if $X \in [a, b]$ and $x<a$ then

$$F(x)=P(X \leq x)=P(X\leq x <a)=P(\emptyset)=0 \hspace{0.3cm} \text{because} \hspace{0.3cm} a \leq X <a \hspace{0.3cm} \text{is contradictory}$$

On another hand $X \in [a, b]$ and $x\geq b$, in this case I don't know how to proceed, I think that inequalities should lead us to $P(\Omega)=1$ but i dont know how. Any suggestions? I appreciate it!

Comment: To me there is almost nothing to prove it directly follows from the definition of the CDF it is just a matter of writing the thing properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>b$; $F(x)=\int_{-\infty} ^ x f(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x) dx+\int_{a}^b f(x) dx+ \int_{b}^x f(x) dx$.

Since all values of $f(x)$ lie in $[a,b]$, so $\int_{-\infty}^a f(x) dx=\int_{b}^x f(x) dx=0$.

Moreover, using the definition of probability density function, $\int_{a}^b f(x) dx=1$.

Thus, we have $F(x)=\int_{-\infty} ^ x f(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^a f(x) dx+\int_{a}^b f(x) dx+ \int_{b}^x f(x) dx=\int_{a}^b f(x) dx=1$.

Comment: Density function for $X$ may not exist.

Comment: I do not get why this answer gets upvoted regarding the comment above this one. This answer is not appropriate as it makes an additionnal assumption on $X$ while the statement in question is more general.